# Routing Error while editing comments in ruby on rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

My app was working fine until I decided to add edit functionality for comments. Before it, I could view particular article but not now. I have added edit.html.erb page in comments views and has _comment_form.html.erb as partial.Now I can not visit article/12( for example) and when I try, it says `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :article_id=>#<Article id: 21, title: "good for health", body: "uby on Rails 3 Model Data Validation\r\nRails Model D...", created_at: "2013-04-14 15:14:19", updated_at: "2013-04-24 05:51:20", user_id: 1, impressions_count: 7>, :id=>#<Comment id: nil, content: nil, user_id: nil, article_id: 21, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}`

Basically, I am trying to implement comments editing functionality on articles/show page. For this, I added edit.html.erb under comments views. But now nothing is working. Any suggestion would be appreciating.

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :user_signed_in, except: [:create]
    def new
      @comment = Comment.new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
      @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
      @comment.user_id = current_user.id
      @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
        redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
    end

    def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
     @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
     @article = @comment.article
     respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        redirect_to @article_path(@article)
      else
       render :action => "edit" 
      end
    end

    def destroy
     @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment.destroy
       redirect_to @article_path(@artilce) 
    end

end
```

comments/edit.html.erb

```
<h3>Editing comment</h3>
<%= render :partial => 'comment_form' %>
```

comments/_comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build]), :required => true do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :article_id %> 
 <%= f.text_area :content, :style => "width:727px; height:100px; border: 1px solid #999999;margin-top:80px; background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-left:-33px" %>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Comment", :style => "margin-right:20px; margin-left:560px; background-color:#66C9Ef; color:#FFFFFF; border: 0px solid #82b548; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; font-size: 1.3rem;" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

comments/comment.html.erb ( here i have given link for editing comments for an article)

```
<% if @article.comments.count  >= 1 %>
  <div style="border: px solid #66c9ee;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;margin: 10px -30px 15px; padding:     10px 15px 25px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2F2F2; width:700px; font-size: 1.2em;border-bottom: 0px solid #DDDDDD;">
      <%= comment.content %>
         <div id="tabula"> 
            <ul id="tabula">
             <li> <div style="color: #0077CC;margin-rigth:200px; font-size: 1.0em;margin-top:4px;background-color:#;"> <%= comment.user.username if comment.user %></div></li>
             <li> <div style="color: #0077CC; background-color:; margin-top:4px; margin-left:25px;"> <p> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at.in_time_zone("Asia/Calcutta"))  unless comment.created_at.nil? %>  </p></div></li>
             <li> <div style="color: #0077CC; background-color:; margin-top:4px; margin-left:25px;"> <%= link_to "edit", edit_article_comment_path(@article,comment) %> </div></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
    <% else %>
        <div style="color:#0077CC;margin-left:25px;font-size:1.4em;"> be first to comment</div>
  <% end %>
```

routes.rb (not full)

```
        articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                 POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
     new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
    edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
         article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                 PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                 DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
 dashboard_index GET    /dashboard(.:format)                              dashboard#index
                 POST   /dashboard(.:format)                              dashboard#create
   new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)                          dashboard#new
  edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)                     dashboard#edit
       dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#show
                 PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#update
                 DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#destroy


               tags GET    /tags(.:format)                                   tags#index
                     POST   /tags(.:format)                                   tags#create
             new_tag GET    /tags/new(.:format)                               tags#new
            edit_tag GET    /tags/:id/edit(.:format)                          tags#edit
                 tag GET    /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#show
                     PUT    /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#update
                     DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#destroy
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                     GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
                     GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
                     GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
                     GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
```

routes.rb

```
Mau::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'articles#index'
  resources :articles
  resources :dashboard
  resources :tags
  resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
end
```

Note: When I visit an article which does not have comments, It works, but when i try to visit an article which has comments , it shows above routing error. Any suggestion would be appreciating.

Answer (score 0):

i'm too low ranked to comment, however
please post your routes file, but i think there could be a problem here `/articles/:article_id/comments`

your comment in edit does not have an ID. Is it a fresh variable? Please investigate in that direction

Comment: hi Alive, thanks for your response. I have posted my routes.rb file. Please have look at this. I did not get about "/articles/:article_id/comments" and where you want to change. Please elaborate it more.

Comment: What you posted me is the product of `rake routes`. I want the `routes.rb` file content

Comment: sorry Alive. here is routes.rb:- Mau::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'articles#index'
  resources :articles
  resources :dashboard
  resources :tags
  resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
end

Comment: i have updated question with routes.rb file. please have look there.

Answer (score 0):

1. try commenting the edit link and check whether it works..
   if it works , then the problem is in the edit comment method.
2. your path should be edit_article_comment_path(article_id ,comment_id) since comment is a nested controller it will always need an article id to show up

Comment: hi TechGuy, you are right, when I comment edit link,it works. but i need to implement editing comments. any suggestion.

Comment: hi TechGuy, I have changed edit path to edit_article_comment_path(attherate article_id , atherate comment_id) as per your second suggestion but with little changes. I have used @ article_id  and  @ comment_id . but now I get Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments", :article_id=>nil, :id=>nil}